# Scrolling and Swiping in Android

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, touch-event

I have layout with **ViewPager** and **ScrollView** like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/now_playing_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/lyrics_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView              
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
            />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now,Textview is Scrolling as expected **But on swiping viewpager is not working as it is below ScrollView.**

So,when Scrolled ScrollView should work and when swiped Viewpager should.

In Short,what I want is:

moved in Y Direction--->ScrollView

moved in X Direction--->ViewPager

Code below detects that i m moving in X-direction:

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   switch (event.getAction()) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mLastX = event.getX();
        mLastY = event.getY();
        mStartX = mLastX;
        break;       
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        float xDelta = Math.abs(x - mLastX);
        float yDelta = Math.abs(y - mLastY);

        float xDeltaTotal = x - mStartX;
        if (xDelta > yDelta && Math.abs(xDeltaTotal) > mTouchSlop) {
            // moved in X Direction
            mStartX = x;
            return true;
        }
        break;
}

return false;
}
```

Please help me out to achieve desired result

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34252208/5165244) seems like your kind of situation. Have a look.

Comment: Try by setting `setnestedscrollingenabled:"false"` to scrollview

Comment: Hi Aneeb,thanks for the link.It gave me some idea,I will try to implement it.